# How to get moment-timezone current configured timezone?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

So when we configure a default timezone using `moment-timezone` we do something like this:

```js
moment.tz.setDefault('America/Sao_Paulo')
```

I was looking for a way to retrieve that value (`America/Sao_Paulo`) from the moment.tz object... I wasn't able to find it on their [documentation page](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) :/ I was assuming it would be something similar to `moment.tz.getCurrent() // America/Sao_Paulo`

Btw, this is not the same as `moment.tz.guess()`, because I don't want the user's local timezone, I want literally what is the timezone configured currently on moment, regardless of the browser's timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also in a similar boat. There appears to be an undocumented attribute on moment that is set after you guess the timezone.

```
moment.defaultZone
```

Haven't found how it can be used with other moment-timezone methods yet.

Comment: Oh, looks like `moment.defaultZone.name` returns exactly what I need. I was looking for an attribute inside `moment.tz`, probably why I didn't find that. Thanks!